# MS Word 2016: Table is splitting across pages even though set not to

Tags: microsoft-word, table-styles

I'm using MS Word 2016 to create a word document that is going to be used as a template.

I'm using a fairly small table for the signature block, and I need the rows to not split apart onto a new page when it loses space on the current page. I have "Allow row to break across pages" unchecked, and the entire document style property is set to "Keep lines together".

And yet my table still breaks between pages rather than jumping to the next page as a whole unit. What am I missing?

[image: Example of splitting table]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### What am I missing?

> 1. Select all the rows in the table.
> 2. Display the Home tab of the ribbon.
> 3. Click the small icon at the bottom-right of the Paragraph group. Word displays the Paragraph dialog box.
>
>    [image]
> 4. Make sure the Line and Page Breaks tab is selected.
> 5. Make sure the Keep Lines Together check box is selected.
> 6. Click on OK.
>
> Now you need to repeat the same steps, with two minor variations:
>
> - First, in step 1 select all the rows except the last one.
> - Then, in step 5, make sure the Keep With Next check box is selected.
>
>   This is necessary (performing this step with the last row not
>     selected) so that the table stays together as a unit, rather than the
>     table staying with the paragraph that follows it.

Source [Keeping Tables on One Page (Microsoft Word)](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T012975_Keeping_Tables_on_One_Page)

Comment: This worked beautifully. Thank you!!